# Javascript Canvas Uncaught TypeError: document.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas, browser

I am trying to draw a simple canvas but my browser shows an error, I am doing this by a tutorial and wondering where the mistake is.
Thanks in advance

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>doc</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
        <script src="js.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
   var canvas = document.getElementById('c1');
   var ctx = document.getContext('2d');
   ctx.fillRect(100,50,150,75);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `getContext` is method of the canvas element.

So instead of `document.getContext('2d')` try `canvas.getContext('2d')`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext for more information

Answer (score 0):

`let ctxA = document.querySelector("#canvas1").getContext("2d");`

`let ctxB = document.querySelector("#canvas2").getContext("2d");`

These lines grab the `<canvas id='canvas1'>  <canvas id='canvas2'>` DOM elements and then identify the context of the respective canvas.

The context object is what contains all the drawing methods etc, so that's what you really want - you'll reference the context object much more often than the canvas object.

note that if you *do* want the canvas object you can reference it in the `ctx.canvas` property.